# Initialize unreferenced project in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

I have a web application solution with 2 projects. I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Project "A" has all the website elements, and it creates events to which project "B" reacts doing stuff. Project "A" is the entry point, and project "B" has a reference to "A" so that it can subscribe to A's events.

My problem is that project "A" cannot reference project "B" (that would be cyclic!), so "B" is never called (not even static constructors) and it cannot subscribe to "A" or do anything at all.

If I make "B" the entry point, sure enough, constructors and everything get called, but then I don't know how to correctly make project "A" start (unsurprisingly, the website is not created).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this problem in Visual Studio, as in you are trying to debug your projects?

Comment: This sounds like a solution design issue.

Comment: Yes, I am working in Visual Studio and I am building in debug mode for the moment.

Comment: And yes, it is possible the design of the project is not optimal, although I believe it makes sense: "A" creates the website, the interface with the user. And creates events so that other programs can do their things. Does that sound problematic? (This is my first time working with more than one project!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with your architecture.

Whoever holds the reference to the other should be considered the gate keeper and should initialize the other upon startup.

In your case, B should not be subscribing to A. A should be instantiating B and doing whatever event wire-up is needed so B can "react".

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about this. I will try to figure out how to subscribe B to A from A, it makes sense that this should be possible if A holds a reference to B!

Comment: It worked perfectly. I had always subscribed events from the listener, but I am glad to see the same sentence works if written on the sender!